# Reduce indentation when using Python nested loops

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Is there a way to reduce the indentation when using nested loops, as per below?

```
for source_i in sources:
    for source_j in sources:
        for ni in source_i.nodes:
            for nj in source_j.nodes:
                if ni != nj:
                    do_thing(ni, nj)
```

Comment: Move the `do_thing` line to the beginning with a `[` before it; take out all new lines and colons; add a `]` to the end.  Voila!  But please don't do that.  List comprehensions are easy ways to create lists.  It is not a good idea to create a list of the returns of `do_thing(...)` if you aren't going to use it.  List comprehensions should be used for creating lists, not for their side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for source_i in sources:
    for source_j in sources:
        pass
```

This is the same thing as iterating through the pairs in the Cartesian product of `sources` and itself. This can be written in one line by importing `itertools`:

```
import itertools
for (i,j) in itertools.product(sources, repeat=2):
    pass
```

Same pattern here:

```
for ni in i.nodes:
    for nj in j.nodes:
        pass
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
for (ni, nj) in itertools.product(i.nodes, j.nodes):
    pass
```

So now you can nest them:

```
import itertools
for (i,j) in itertools.product(sources, repeat=2):
    for (ni, nj) in itertools.product(i.nodes, j.nodes):
        if ni != nj:
            do_thing(ni, nj)
```

Comment: `product(sources, sources)` can also be written as `product(sources, repeat=2)` - comes handy especially when we want more than a 2-dimensional product of an iterable with itself.

Comment: @plamut Yes, I have it at the top and forgot to copy it down. :) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one way to replace nested loops is to use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

for source_i, source_j in product(sources, repeat=2):
  for ni, nj in product(source_i.nodes, source_j.nodes):
      ...
```

The `product` function does a *"Cartesian product of input iterables"* (directly from the docs).